# Form Fitting TextArea

Tags: html, css, layout, textarea

I am working on a project where I want the user on a website to be able to input text into w3-cells.

I am using w3 cells because they automatically change shape to fit the page, but I am having issues making a textArea to automatically change shape with the layout.

It seems to me that the HTML is not even being changed by the CSS, but I cannot find any bugs in my code :/.

Note: The CSS for the textArea of the ideaText works fine; my problem is with the bodyCells.

HTML:

```
<div id="top">
  <div id="idea">
    <textArea id="ideaText" placeholder="Introduce your topic here...">
    </textArea>
  </div>
  <div id="body">
    <div class="w3-cell-row" id="bodyCells">
      <div id="evidence1" class="w3-container w3-red w3-cell">
        <textArea placeholder = "Write some stuff...">
        </textArea>
      </div>
      <div id="evidence2" class="w3-container w3-green w3-cell">
        <textArea></textArea>
      </div>
      <div id="evidence3" class="w3-container w3-yellow w3-cell">
        <textArea></textArea>
      </div>
      <div id="evidence4" class="w3-container w3-blue w3-cell">
        <textArea></textArea>
      </div>
      <div id="evidence5" class="w3-container w3-purple w3-cell">
        <textArea></textArea>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

CSS:

```
#idea{
  background: #b35900;
  height: 150px;
}

textArea#ideaText{
  background: rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  width: 100%;
  height: 150px;
  font-size: 28px;
}

textArea#bodyCells{
  background: rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  width: 100%;
  height: 150px;
  font-size: 28px;
}

 .w3-cell-row#bodyCells{
   height: 150px;
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have wrong css selector, which don't "catch" the html elements you want. There is no `textArea#bodyCells` in your html. `textArea#bodyCells` search for `<textArea id="bodyCells">`, which don't exists in you view. This is why it looks like css is not working at all for that element.

Btw, I advice you to only use classes (without ids) in css selectors. Simpler selectors will be easier to maintain and develop. :)

Comment: Thank you very much. I went through and put the same ID in each textarea, which works.

Answer (score 0):

It's just a tiny mistake in the order of the selectors.
What you've typed:

```
textArea#bodyCells{}
```

What it should be:

```
#bodyCells textArea{}
```

[Here's your code](https://jsfiddle.net/ZechariahRaman/L7j8nzfr/) working just as you want it to... I hope.

:)